# Remove dot-after-number in figure captions while keeping the dot in chapter/section captions

Tags: sectioning, captions, koma-script, punctuation, appendices

In my document (using KOMAScript and babel[ngerman]) I have various figures which get captions like "Abbildung 1: ...".

However, as soon as I add a `\appendix` to the document all those captions change to "Abbildung 1.: ..." (dot in front of the colon). Apparently this is a feature - I want to disable it anyway!

Using `pointlessnumbers` in the `\documentclass` options I can get rid of this dott - but then I also lose the dot in chapter/section numbers which I want to keep since "1. Introduction" looks much better than just "1 Introduction".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using the `pointlessnumbers` class option, remove `\autodot` from the definition of `\figureformat`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{%
  \figurename~\thefigure%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\section{blubb}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\appendix

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just had the same problem with the 'dot' in the figure, respectively table.

Found that

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
```

does the same trick and is much easier than using renewcommands. Just add it to your existing preambles, separated by comma, e.g.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
```

Comment: The OP wanted to get rid of the closing dots in captions, but wanted to keep the dots for chapters/sections. That's what my `\renewcommand` was for. :-)