# Can not redefine the command of \figureformat (\figureformat undefined)

Tags: numbering, captions, punctuation, naming

I want to redefine the \figureformat to customize the output of figure captions:

```
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{\thefigure.\figurename}
```

However, it gives an error when I compile:

```
\figureformat undefined. \renewcommand*{\figureformat}
```

Here is the test tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{\thefigure. \figurename}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{{test}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am using TeX Live 2013/W32TeX and TexStudio

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this command?

Comment: @Johannes_B Here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27250/remove-dot-after-number-in-figure-captions-while-keeping-the-dot-in-chapter-sect

Comment: There is your answer, `figureformat` is only defined with KOMA-classes. With the standard classes, you can use package `caption` to do it with a nice interface.

Comment: @Johannes_B The problem is I want to change the format only for figures. I want the format of tables to remain unchanged. If I use caption interface, I will change both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you cannot redefine is only provided by KOMA-classes. For the standard classes, package `caption`comes in handy. You can define the labelformat for just figures, if you want to. Tables will stay the same.

[image: leoCaptionFormat]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{figure}{\thefigure.\nobreakspace\figurename}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=figure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{figure caption}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{table caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works like a charm.